# How to reconfigure a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, data-munging

I'm trying to reconfigure a pandas dataframe, which currently looks like this:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  7   5   2   1   2   2
1  3   4   3   1   4   6
2  1   3   2   6   5   5
```

into something like this:

```
   c1  c2  c3  
0  7   5   2
0  1   2   2
1  3   4   3
1  1   4   6
2  1   3   2   
2  6   5   5
```

(trying to split the dataframe and then place the latter slice underneath as a new row - c1,c2,c3 are new column labels)

Comment: In your real data is `len(df.columns) % 3` always `0` ?

Comment: nope, the length of the columns is 75000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive here is necessary reshape values to 3 columns, only necessary modulo of length of columns is `0`:

```
print (len(df.columns) % 3)
0

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 3), 
                  columns=[f'c{x}' for x in range(1, 4)], 
                  index = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns) / 3))
print (df)

   c1  c2  c3
0   7   5   2
0   1   2   2
1   3   4   3
1   1   4   6
2   1   3   2
2   6   5   5
```

EDIT:

I try simulate your problem - added new column `G` and get output in 3 columns:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F   G
0  7  5  2  1  2  2  10
1  3  4  3  1  4  6  20
2  1  3  2  6  5  5  30
```

If need all values in output, then for values from end are added `NaN`s, because not exist:

```
N = 3
c = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [c % N, c // N]

df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = [f'{x + 1}' for x in df.columns]
print (df)
    1    2    3
0   7  5.0  2.0
1   1  2.0  2.0
2  10  NaN  NaN
3   3  4.0  3.0
4   1  4.0  6.0
5  20  NaN  NaN
6   1  3.0  2.0
7   6  5.0  5.0
8  30  NaN  NaN
```

Another idea is remove columns which created NaNs by indexing - here column `G`:

```
N = 3
c = len(df.columns)
last = (c % N)

df = df.iloc[:, :-last]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  7  5  2  1  2  2
1  3  4  3  1  4  6
2  1  3  2  6  5  5
```

And then use original solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 3), 
                  columns=[f'c{x}' for x in range(1, 4)], 
                  index = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns) / 3))
print (df)
   c1  c2  c3
0   7   5   2
0   1   2   2
1   3   4   3
1   1   4   6
2   1   3   2
2   6   5   5
```

Comment: Thanks @ jezrael. I have simplified the df for the question. My actual df I'm working on 100x75000 shaped df. I'm trying to get for each current row, the 0 to 3725 columns stored as the first row of a new df. Then the next 3725  to 75000 columns stored in a second row of the new df

Comment: Not to sure if this part of the function  "len(df.columns)/3)", will give me the correct df required?

Comment: @user341383 - because length of columns have to be diviable by 3 with no residual

Comment: okay, I see. For my actual df, what I will need to do is len(df.columns)/2 , to get 3750 columns?

Comment: @user341383 - so in your real data this is impossible. So your problem should be simulate, if add new column `G` and still need 3 columns in output. So what is expected output if one new column `G` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns is divisible by 3 and you want unique index names:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7.0, 3.0, 1.0],
          'B': [5.0, 4.0, 3.0],
          'C': [2.0, 3.0, 2.0],
          'D': [1.0, 1.0, 6.0],
          'E': [2.0, 4.0, 5.0],
          'F': [2.0, 6.0, 5.0]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,3), columns = ['c1','c2','c3'])

print(df1)

    c1   c2   c3
0  7.0  5.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  4.0  3.0
3  1.0  4.0  6.0
4  1.0  3.0  2.0
5  6.0  5.0  5.0
```